# How do I call a separate python program using a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a button in tkinter and when pressed, have that button call a different program into this program. (this is just an example) Say I have the one program that shows the button that says "Square root" and I have another program that takes a number such as: 4, using the input() function, and finds the square root of 4. I want that button when pressed to call the "square root program" and input it into the "button" program. (Again. just an example. if I really wanted to do the square root stuff I would just make a different function called: def square_root())

```
#Button.py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def call_the_other_program():
    #This is the part I don't know how to do...
    #Do I import the different program somehow?
    #Is this even possible xD
b = Button(root, text = "Square root", command = call_the_other_program())
```

Square root program:

```
import math
x = input("input a number")
print("the square root of", x, "is:", math.sqrt(x))
#I want this to be the program that is called
```

Thanks for explaining to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function `square_root` in the `other_prog.py`, import it and call it.

I would suggest that you keep all the related files in the same folder to start with, so as not to complicate the import process.

#### other_prog.py

```
import math

def square_root():
    x = float(input('enter a square'))
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

#### GUI.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from other_prog import square_root


def call_square_root():
    print(f'the square root is {square_root()}')


root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text = "Square root", command=call_square_root())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The example is a little bit contrived; the button command could directly be `square_root`, as it is in the `NameSpace` after import.